# if else statement at copying and pasting a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which will copy/paste some columns from  "data" worksheet and pastes to the next empty column in  to the column that i specify in the mastersheet called "KomKo".

```
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("data")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("KoMKo")
lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With copySheet.Range("BX2:BX" & lRow)
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With
```

Now i would like to add an if condition for another column; which should say "if column U in Worksheet "data" has cell value "8636" then these values should be pasted to Column H in Worksheet "KomKo"(pastesheet); to the next row as i used the code above in the "with" part.

Else( If the value in Column H is not 8636) then it should paste the value inside this column to Column G at Worksheet "KomKo"(pastesheet) with same preferences as above again.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've come up with a suggestion below using an if-then within a loop. I think it's close to what you want...

```
Sub try6()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Dim x As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("data")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("KomKo")

For Each x In ws.Range("C1:C100")
    If x.Value = 8636 Then
     ws2.Range("H:H").Value = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").Value
         ElseIf x <> 8636 Then
        ws2.Range("G:G").Value = ws.Range(Rows.Count, "B").Value
      End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Testing it, it took a while to execute. I'd say, set a dynamic range at something like A10000 and copy it directly without needing to necessarily test for whether there is a value in the range being copied.

You can also use the Select method for the purpose and copy the selection - from personal experience, I've had mixed success with it and I've seen people advise against using it here.

These are my .02, hope it helps! Cheers.